# Not able to start Sqlite driver on Wildfly

Tags: sqlite, wildfly

I have deployed sqlite driver on wildfly successfully, but driver service  is not starting up, I am getting error - - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [org.sqlite]". I have already added module.xml under "/system/layer/base/org/sqlite/main/" and I have copied my jar files also there.  Updated my standalone.xml

```
                <driver name="sqlite" module="org.sqlite">
                    <driver-class>org.sqlite.JDBC</driver-class>
```

what else I am missing. Any kind of leads will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Here is the `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.sqlite" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: can anyone clarify module name and class name of sqlite driver is correct or not?

Comment: Can you dump the content of your "module.xml" file ?

Comment: yes sure....below is the info. you need.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.sqlite">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqlite-jdbc-3.6.20.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>

Comment: Is the version (1.5) in the module namespace ("urn:jboss:module:1.5") correct ? Depending on Wildfly version, it can be 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, etc... Compare with another existing module of /system/layer/base, to ensure it's the correct one

Comment: it is actually 1.8, so are  you suggesting to change it from 1.5 to 1.8 and then try?

Comment: Yes that's what I suggest indeed; a wrong version number *might* prevent the module from being properly loaded

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for your timely help, you rocked. It worked and now my driver service is running.

Comment: Glad to see it is working now.